# How to block shutdown in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

Sometime I run maintenance scripts in a machine. I want to temporally block users from been able to shuting-down the system while this task are running. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "block shutdown"?

Comment: change the permission `chmod -x /sbin/shutdown`

Comment: @devav2 I think the OP is asking about the shutdown icon. This can and should be runnable with root permissions.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ Yeah. I'm not very clear about what he is looking for.

Comment: When running script update-manager

Comment: Is your system shutting down while running update manager  ?

Comment: I need when the user click on shutdown button, the shutting down progress been blocked. I need that because maintenance tasks are been doing. When the process blocked, I will show a message about that.
Thanks a lot for all!